# Dynamic tiles windows-8 style in CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently trying to find a good solution to [mimic Windows 8 tiles](http://winsupersite.com/site-files/winsupersite.com/files/archive/winsupersite.com/content/content/143175/tiles-01.jpg). I don't care about 100% browser support, so I choose a [flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#main-axis) approach.
Here's my draft: **http://jsfiddle.net/8fo5qj9z/**

Goal would be:

required:

- every tile should be a square
- all tiles should be of the same size (width, height)
- we declare how many tiles per line we want to show
- the square size is changed dynamicly, to fit the parent-div width with as many tiles per line as we just declared
- how many lines we get depends on how many tiles we create
- content within a single tile is dynamicly shrinked / grown (to a resonable degree)
- below / above that resonable degree we use e.g. `@media only screen` to change the tile content
- content is primarily text but may be more complex too
- in case of text we want to use something like `overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;` on multi-line text so text get's trimmed if it ever reaches the end of a tile.

optional:

- if a single tile's content requires more space (controlable using e.g. padding) it is allowed to grow to a multiple-size of a single title but maximum to the size of a single line.

**As you can see in my draft above I currently strugge with multiple things:**

- text trimming when it reaches the end of the tile without the tile to grow
- thus tiles are not always squares
- I'm currently using `33vw` to make sure we got 3 tiles per line but this seems not to work well when placed inside a div in some browsers , e.g. firefox. The tiles make up 33% of the hole page instead of 33% the parent-div. I wonder if there is a better solution for the max tiles-per-line / row thing.
- no idea how to do the optional part

Comment: Of course `33vw` returns 33% of the window width. That's exactly what `vw` (viewport width) is. `33vw = 33% of viewport width`. If you want 33% of a parent element, then you simply need percentage. 33.333% = 1/3 of the parent width.

Comment: You're right, that fixed the issue with firefox. Wonder why it worked in chrome using vw. Yet I still got issues with the text trimming.